# Adding a new row to a table in jQuery but apply unique ID to input names

Tags: javascript, jquery

so im building an invoice tool and i need to be able to add a new row so add a new product which contain inputs with names and id values.

I have the following JS which is creating the new rows perfectly for me however any ideas how i can adjust so it finds name="blah" and id="blah" on inputs and select lists and adds to the end _1, _2, _3 etc... numbers being for each new row.

JS:

```
// add new product row on invoice
    $(".add-row").click(function () {
        $("#invoice_table").each(function () {
            var tds = '<tr>';
            jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {
                tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
            });
            tds += '</tr>';
            if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
                $('tbody', this).append(tds);
            } else {
                $(this).append(tds);
            }
        });

        return false
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the index available in your `$.each`... like:

```
    $(".add-row").click(function () {
        $("#invoice_table").each(function () {
            var tds = '<tr>';
            jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function (index, element) {
                var html = $(this).html().replace(/blah/g, 'blah_'+index);
                tds += '<td>' + html + '</td>';
            });
            tds += '</tr>';
            if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
                $('tbody', this).append(tds);
            } else {
                $(this).append(tds);
            }
        });

        return false
    });
```

Comment: Im not sure, I found that snippet online which helped me add it and not sure how to adjust to my needs. Im pretty new to this.

Comment: There will be about 6 different ones i need to add _+index to, should i add multiple replace?

Comment: I guess i need it to find and replace, i would use markup within the JS but some select lists are populated with PHP.

Comment: there, fixed it for you to replace all instances of the word 'blah' within the html

Comment: Thanks Ted, would I just replicate that though for each input ID? example i have like 6 inputs with different IDs you see. name="product_name" id="product_name", name="product_qty" id="product_qty" etc... sorry to be a pain and thanks so much for your help.

Comment: that would be one way of handling it

Comment: I added var html $...(), $...(), $....(); for each one but get the error: Unexpected token ( anything im doing wrong here?

Comment: I got it working but its doing _0 and then _0_0 and then _0_0_0 etc... rather than _1, _2, _3, _4 and so forth.

Comment: id have to see a complete example...can you create a fiddle?

Comment: yep 2 secs, ill create one now.

Comment: Hi Ted, did you managed to figure it out? ive had no luck as of yet. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can use counter for it

```
$("#invoice_table").each(function () {
            var count=0;
            var tds = '<tr>';
            jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {
                var count=count+1;
                tds += '<td id="blah'+counter+'" name="blah'+counter+'">' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
            });
            tds += '</tr>';
            if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
                $('tbody', this).append(tds);
            } else {
                $(this).append(tds);
            }
        });

        return false
```

So that everytime it creates a unique identifier

Comment: I need to find and replace really as i cannot build it using JS for the markup as some sleect lists are populated with PHP you see.